# Will an empty Cloudformation Stack cost money?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

AWS docs say you only pay for what you use.

Just wondering if the "Stack" by itself costs something.
If I create an empty Cloudformation Stack without any resources, will it have some costs associated with it?

Comment: You can't create an empty stack, it must have at least one resource.

Comment: @TimBassett I did not realize that. I was just concerned if it'll cost more if I split my resources to multiple Stacks as opposed to one Stack.

Comment: Nope, CF is free, you only pay for the resources it creates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty stack, with no resources, will not cost you any money.

From the [cloudformation docs](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/pricing/) (emphasis is mine):

> There is **no additional charge for using AWS CloudFormation** with
> resource providers in the following namespaces: AWS::*, Alexa::*, and
> Custom::*. In these cases, you pay for AWS resources such as Amazon
> Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instances, Elastic Load Balancing load
> balancers, etc. created using AWS CloudFormation **the same as if you
> had created them manually**

so even if the stack is not empty, when using the standard resource providers, leveraging cloudformation will not cost you anything extra.